# Facebook JS API: User does not stay connected

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a simple web app where users can login via Facebook to CRUD objects (and show them on a map).

I successfully implemented the login and logout functions using the [full example code](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/#example) from Facebook documentation, but **the user doesn't stay logged in**.

When I log in, I'm able to display the my Facebook Surname and Name, but when I refresh or go to the next page of my app, the Facebook API tells me that I'm not connected (anymore) and thus I have to reconnect.

The same happens with the full example code. On page refresh: you have to login again.

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Have you tried setting `status: true` in the SDK initialization? What browser are you using this in, are 3rd-party cookies allowed, did you disable all extensions to make sure none of them were interfering?

Comment: Yes I put status: true and cookie: true in sdk init. Using stock chrome and also tried in firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was pretty dumb but my browser (chrome) was blocking cookies from facebook.com on my website, so I couldn't stay logged.
Resolved the problem by authorizing facebook.com cookies on my website.